# Outlook 2010 categories ... hide contact categories in calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have categories like "friends" for my contacts. I don't want these to appear when I am creating events in the calendar. Instead, my calendar only has a few categories, like "Important", "Off Work", etc. Is there any way to hide those categories I'm using in contacts from the dropbox of categories in new calendar events?

(There is one way: once I organize the contacts, remove those contacts from the master category list. But this is not ideal.)